# Using R and ggplot, how would I plot data with 3 x variables that all have multiple time values

Tags: python, r, ggplot2

so I am new to R and I am having trouble on figuring out how I would plot this data. I guess I am confused on how to use the aes function in ggplot, because I do not understand how I would categorize the x and y if I have 3 columns of data with a bunch of various times beneath each.

```
Grubhub Postmates Doordash
    2       4         5
    5       8         9 
    2       2         8
    29      8         17
    12      23        98
```

I am trying to achieve this result:

[image: the end goal]

How would I use ggplot to do this? I am so lost, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to format data to long. One good practice in `ggplot2` is to reshape data so that all aesthetics devices can work well. You data is in format known as `wide`. In order to transform it you can use `tidyverse` functions like `pivot_longer()` and `everything()` to adjust the format of your data. With that done, you can sketch the plot as seen in the code. Here the solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code to reshape data to long
df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Grubhub = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 29L, 12L), Postmates = c(4L, 
8L, 2L, 8L, 23L), Doordash = c(5L, 9L, 8L, 17L, 98L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Ans if you want to remove the legend, you can adjust the `theme()` option:

```
#Code to reshape data to long 2
df %>% pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,color=name,group=name))+
  geom_point()+
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

Output:

[image]